# Debugging Timer Jobs

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs, debugging

It has been awhile since I tried to debug a timer job; the last time was on SP2010.
I have a job that updates some values in a list and I want to debug the code.  I am attaching to OWSTIMER.EXE and I can see that some of my list values are altered, so I know that it ran, however VS never stops at my break point, which is at the start of the Execute method.  The articles I have read, indicate that this should work.  Did something change between SP 2013 or there something else I need to do?

Comment: Nothing change in 2013. Did you restart the Timer Service after performing the deploy.

Comment: @Marco can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing change in 2013. 
Did you restart the Timer Service after performing the deploy?. After every deploy, you have to restart the timer service.

Greetings